# Using 1 momentary switch to toggle between two latched states. Plus relay question

Tags: switches, flipflop

I know there are many ways to do this, but I'm looking for the easiest setup, not necessarily the cheapest.

I need to build a circuit in which a momentary switch alternates power between two 110v lamps. I believe I need to use a D flip-flop and have the output control a relay, but other than that I'm a little unsure. So, press the momentary open switch once, lamp 1 illuminates, press again, lamp 2 comes on. Simple as that.

I don't want to use any microcontrollers. I want to see if I can do this with minimal components. In this case the relays are just operating like transistors, at least from what I can tell.

Is there a simple way to use a spdt relay and just use the flip flop to toggle relay positions? What specific relays should I be looking for? (solid state or mechanical?) And is there a simple flip-flop IC that would work well for this?

I've considered just using a SPST high power switch, but for this project I need to use a specific arcade-style momentary pushbutton and therefore looking for a workaround.

I have to have it built within the week, I really appreciate anyone's help. Thank you, and I apologize if this question comes up a lot.

Comment: Also, in this case I would be using an AC relay, right? not DC?

Answer (score 2):

A bi-stable latching relay would be a simple solution.

[image]

*Figure 1. Go to [HomoFaciens](http://www.homofaciens.de/technics-base-circuits-relay_en.htm) and click "Start animation" to see how the pawl mechanism is advanced on every impulse of the relay coil.*

No flip-flops, electronics or magic is required. Wire your button between the power-supply and the coil. Each impulse will change the state of the contact.

Imgur doesn't seem to like animated gifs.

Comment: +1 for sharing that cool animation web link.